# Running fetchmail with Socks proxy

Tags: proxy, socks, fetchmail

I checked the manual of fetchmail, all it mentioned was `SOCKS_CONF`, but what is the format of that config file?

And how do I know if my fetchmail is configured with `--with-socks`, `fetchmail -V` doesn't say anything related.

Comment: In case it's not compiled-in, [this TOR documentation](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/EMail) mentions two ways (plain `tsocks` or `socat` via `fetchmail`'s `plugin` directive) for using `fetchmail` through SOCKS.

Comment: Have a look at [this mailing list thread](http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/fetchmail-users/2007-March/000842.html) discussing `fetchmail` and SOCKS, it's pretty informative (it doesn't tell how `/etc/socks.conf` is supposed to look like, though).